# Class from XML layout that can be instantiated in the main activity

Tags: android, xml, view

So I have this xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10sp"
    android:id="@+id/lengthLayout"
    android:background="@color/gray2"
     >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/inputLength"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.3"
            android:hint="@string/temperatureHint"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            tools:ignore="NestedWeights" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/lengthUnits"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.7" />
    </LinearLayout>

  <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
     />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" 
       >
        <ListView 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:verticalSpacing="10sp"
            android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/results_length"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
            android:dividerHeight="5sp"

                      >

        </ListView>

        </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

and I want to create a class that will use the resources from this XML file. So that when the class is instantiated in the main activity it will add the view to the app .

```
public class LengthFragment extends View implements OnClickListener, OnItemSelectedListener{

 Context rContext;

public LengthFragment(Context context){
    super(context);
    rContext = context;

    inflate(context, R.layout.view_length, null);
}
```

and this is what I am doing in the main activity

```
LengthFragment lF = new LengthFragment(testapp.this);
```

I have even tried passing in the inflator of the main activity to lengthfragment and inflating the view using that inflator but it doesnt work
all it does is gives me a blank view.
Thanks.

also it works when I do this in the main activity 
    LinearLayout l1 = (LinearLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.view_length, null);

but I want to create this view outside of main acttivity but just instantiaing a class in main activity.

Comment: make sure you are calling setContentView in onCreate of Activity?

Comment: setContentView(R.layout.home); home has a viewpager and dynamically adding and removing views.

Comment: where you are passing `lF` instance to setContentView or are you adding `lF` to any layout dynamically ?

Comment: i am adding lF to to viewpager adapter and the viewpager is in the home xml  and the contentview is set to home xml